# JUnit Tests With and Without Certain Classpath File

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, junit4

The Java library that I'm currently working on can be configured with a `.properties` file in the classpath. Now I want to write JUnit tests that do the following:

1. If the file exists, assert that the values in there are loaded.
2. If the file does *not* exit, assert that the default values are loaded.

Is that sort of thing possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Create a temporary `.properties` file in a folder that is on your classpath for testing. Run test.

In second test rename the file to something else, run test, rename file back to original name.

Comment: I see. In a Maven build, I assume that would be the `target/test-classes` folder, right? Is it safe to change stuff in there?

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem to have extra files in there. Just don't rely on it to stay there forever (some clean build may wipe the folder).